# Amending Excel pivot table criteria programatically

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel spreadsheet template, which contains pivot tables having criteria that specify the content of the spreadsheet.

I need to amend that criteria programatically from a macro running in a separate spreadsheet so that the template will feature different content.

What coding would be appropriate to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will update the report filter on a pivot table in a separate workbook.

In this example the report filter is called '**Location**' and it's value is changed to '**West**'

The code assumes that the separate workbook is already open.

```
Sub UpdatePivotFilter()

Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
 PivotFields("Location").CurrentPage = "West"

End Sub
```